# MUI TextField size growing through div transition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-transitions

I'm making a sidebar for my project and I'm using div transitions to give a smooth effect on collapse. However I have Material-ui (v4.12.3) TextField inside, and during the transition of opening the div, the height of the text field changes to 496px. Adding maxHeight style doesn't prevent a limit and once you interact with the field, it returns to normal (16px). Has anyone had this interactions with transition and mui text fields before?

[image: TextField props]